# How can i locate web element for 'dropdown-toggle' window in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dropbox

I can't able to click 'Board' link for the 'dropdown-toggle' window using selenium webdriver.

I have tried

```
cssSelector="a.accordion-toggle" (or) linkText="Board".
```

But it is not working.

SO, kindly give me a solution for how can I locating 'Board' webelement.

Please refer the screenshot.

Thanks,
Vairamuthu.[image]

Comment: What does "not working" means exactly? And please post the html as text, not image.

Comment: I can't able to click 'Board' link to run selenium webdriver suite.

Comment: Again, it doesn't mean anything. You need to tell us *exactly* what is happening and provide the stack trace if you have an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is visibility of that element. Maybe you're trying to click it when the dropdown 'Academic Year' is collapsed and link 'Board' is invisible in the browser.

I see two possible solutions:

1. Click 'Academic Year' (or scroll mouse on it if it works this way) before clicking 'Board'
2. Use click with JavaScript:

> driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Where "driver" - RemoteWebDriver object, "element" - RemoteWebElement

Note that the second solution won't work if the element for 'Board' link is absent in the page source when dropdown is collapsed.